# spring boot remote shell custom command

Tags: java, spring, shell

I try to add a new custom command to the spring boot remote shell without success.
In the documentation is only a groovy example available but I like to use Java do create a new command.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-remote-shell.html
I also check the CRaSH documentation: http://www.crashub.org/1.3/reference.html#_java_commands

I put my class under package commands and crash.commands but I don't see my new command if I connect to the shell via ssh and type help. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my Java Code:

```
package commands;

import org.crsh.cli.Command;
import org.crsh.cli.Usage;
import org.crsh.command.BaseCommand;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class hello extends BaseCommand {

  @Command
  @Usage("Say Hello")
  public String test() {
    return "HELLO";
  }
}
```

Comment: The Spring Boot shell extension treats the commands as Groovy scripts, not as Spring beans. Your Java code will generally be usable as Groovy anyway; just include the source instead of a compiled `.class` file.

Answer (score 2):

If your class is called 'hello', put it in

```
resources/crash/commands/hello/hello.java
```

Having a package statement doesn't matter. 
You don't have to put anything inside src, just have this inside resources.

@Component isn't required.

This class is compiled during runtime. See:

```
org.crsh.lang.impl.java.JavaCompiler#compileCommand
```

Therefor any dependency injection requirements need to be considered accordingly with lazy initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Put the class in the default package (i.e. omit the package statement) and put the Java source for the class in src/main/resources/commands.  Spring/Crash will compile the Java code the first time you invoke the command.  Also, if the class implements a single command the method name should be ‘main’ otherwise users have to type:

```
> hello test
```

You also don't need the @Component annotation on the class as it is not a Spring managed bean.

Comment: If command class sits in default package, it will be omitted by Spring's `componentScan`. How can I use things like services, Spring Data and my beans then?

Comment: An instance of Spring's BeanFactory is made available that you can access in command scripts to obtain service, etc. instances.  Something like:  
  
    `BeanFactory factory = context.attributes['spring.beanfactory']
    MyService service = factory.getBean(MyService.class)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you also tell me how to get context in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question; the context variable above is injected into the Groovy command script automatically.  Using the context you can get the Spring BeanFactory and either pass that into a Java class or pass the required beans into the Java class.